# Grant IIS APPPoll\MyPoolName to read the registry key on Windows 7

Tags: windows, iis

I have searched the web and found the information to grant IIS to read the registry key. However I didn't succeeded. The site as my reference  is http://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed/

I grant the permission for "IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName" from root to the folder; HKEY_LOCAL-MACHINE, HKEY_LOCAL-MACHINE\SOFTWARE, HKEY_LOCAL-MACHINE\SOFTWARE\APPNAME AND HKEY_LOCAL-MACHINE\SOFTWARE\APPNAME\MYFOLDER

When I open the webpage on IE, I still got "access to the registry key  is denied. Would you someone show me what I missed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it with a different app pool account (i.e. a windows account)?

Comment: @MikeCheel If you mean windows account as login account, I did it. I granted permission for myself, I still got error. Also I granted permission to Network Service too.

Comment: So, to be clear, in your app pool called 'MyAppPool' (or whatever) you have associated it with a computer account (local or domain is fine) and then granted security permissions to that key? How are you accessing the key btw?

Comment: @MikeCheel, my code to read the key is like that  RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(RegKey);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It need SetValue, Create Subkey permission and Read Control to work. I solved it.